# Make a Horizontal presentation of table in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table of items with price per location.

```
Select Item, Price, location from ItemTable Order by Item, Location
```

Here is the result set

```
ITEM    Price   Location
1       10      North
1       20      South
2       10      North
2       20      South
3       20      North
3       20      South
```

I want to make the presentation of the final result set horizontal grouped by Item. Expected result will be something like this

```
Item    North   South
1       10      20
2       10      20
3       20      20
```

But I am totally lost already.

I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query like following using conditional aggregate.

```
SELECT item, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN location = 'North' THEN price 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS North, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN location = 'South' THEN price 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS South 
FROM   ItemTable  
GROUP  BY item
```

If you like you can also use `PIVOT` like following.

```
SELECT Item, Price, location 
FROM   ItemTable  
       PIVOT(Sum(price) 
            FOR location IN([North], 
                            [South])) pvt
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/PTF96180)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Pivot feature can be used to achieve this. Use below query:

> With the help of Pivot, you can aggregate your results and transform
>   rows into columns

**Sample Table & Test Data**

```
declare @ItemTable  table
(ITEM int, Price int, Location varchar(20))

insert into @ItemTable
(ITEM,    Price,   Location)
values
(1   ,    10  ,    'North'),
(1  ,     20   ,   'South'),
(2  ,     10   ,   'North'),
(2  ,     20   ,  'South'),
(3  ,     20  ,    'North'),
(3  ,     20  ,    'South')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ITEM, North,South
FROM   @ItemTable 
 PIVOT  
(SUM(Price) FOR Location IN (North,South))tab  
ORDER BY ITEM
```